# Call Async task from start of activity in android

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-activity

I have a Async task like this in my app:

```
 private class getUserSummary extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DashboardActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting sales summary...");
        //pDialog.setTitle("Getting sales summary...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String JsonResponse = null;
        String JsonDATA = "email=my email address";

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            ServiceUrl smf = new ServiceUrl();
            URL url = new URL(smf.getUserSummaryUrl());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            // is output buffer writter
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            //set headers and method
            Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(JsonDATA);
            // json data
            writer.close();

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 400) {
                InputStream inputResponse = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputResponse));
                StringBuffer errorBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String errorLine;
                while ((errorLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    errorBuffer.append(errorLine + "\n");
                }
                Log.i("Error text", errorBuffer.toString());
                return new JSONObject(errorBuffer.toString());
            }
            //Log.i("Response code", String.valueOf(inputStream));

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            //input stream
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                buffer.append(inputLine + "\n");
            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty. No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            JsonResponse = buffer.toString();
            //response data
            Log.i("RESPONSE", JsonResponse);

            return new JSONObject(JsonResponse);

        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        //post operation here
    }
}
```

and calling this in onCreate() method

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    initCollapsingToolbar();


    new getUserSummary().execute();
   }
```

I am running this as soon as user login activity distroyed. that's why I need to call this on onCreate() method. But I am getting this error when the call this in onCreate() method

```
android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity softlogic.computers.softlogicsalesreward.DashboardActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{5329b90 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1002,348} that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:603)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:326)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:109)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:505)
    at softlogic.computers.softlogicsalesreward.DashboardActivity$getUserSummary.onPreExecute(DashboardActivity.java:88)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:551)
    at softlogic.computers.softlogicsalesreward.DashboardActivity.onResume(DashboardActivity.java:65)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1287)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7015)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4323)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3426)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

is there any other event where I can call this? or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you implemented onPostExecute() ?

Comment: add your `OnCreate` and `OnResume()`

Comment: Post activity code too, where you call asyncTask

Comment: refer here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957409/activity-has-leaked-window-com-android-internal-policy-impl-phonewindowdecorvie

Comment: @U.Swap yes. i have implemented post execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your asyncTask must be like this.After see your code it may possible that You may forgot some method of AsyncTask.Compare with this example to better understand.

This is complete example of asyncTask:

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String resp;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        publishProgress("Sleeping..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
        try {
            int time = Integer.parseInt(params[0])*1000;

            Thread.sleep(time);
            resp = "Slept for " + params[0] + " seconds";
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp = e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            resp = e.getMessage();
        }
        return resp;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // execution of result of Long time consuming operation
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        finalResult.setText(result);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "ProgressDialog",
                "Wait for "+time.getText().toString()+ " seconds");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
        finalResult.setText(text[0]);

    }
}
```

call like this:

```
new AsyncTaskRunner (this).execute();
```

Comment: I have implemented Async task correctly. but can not call in activity's onCreate() method.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. and thank you everyone. there was problem with `getUserSummaryUrl()` method which caused this error. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You Forget to call pDialog.dismiss();
in onPostExecute method of Async task

Comment: I call pDialog.dismiss(); in onPostExecute() method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use thread policy for this. It's work great.
Just add two line below setcontent.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
     .detectAll()
     .penaltyLog()
     .build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```